# MouseEnter MouseLeave in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, mouseevent

I have problem, while writing a program for drawing figures from a text file. My program is currently reading figures from a text file and drawing them  on the canvas, but I have problem with MouseEnter and MouseLeave Events.

I would like the polygon to change colour if there is the mouse over it. How can I do this?

The app is written in WPF, using the `Canvas` control.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some more details on the issue you encounter. What do you have so far?

Comment: What problem are you having with the events?  Are you having trouble with the painting or event handling?

Comment: You could try the IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged event. MouseLeave operates on the Bounds of an elmenet, I would expect that to mean the bounding box.

Comment: Now, my program drawing figures in canvas. I used to draw Polygon and PoinCollection. If my mouse touch the figure then I want to change color of figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [event triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.  For example:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Polygon">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Polygon.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="Yellow"
                                            />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Polygon.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="Blue"
                                            />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Polygon Fill="Blue" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50">
        <Polygon.Points>
            <Point>0,0</Point>
            <Point>20,0</Point>
            <Point>25,5</Point>
            <Point>20,20</Point>
            <Point>0,20</Point>
            <Point>0,0</Point>
        </Polygon.Points>
    </Polygon>

</Canvas>
```

Comment: McGarnagle Thanks a lot, I want it, it run :)